# Error al regresar a la Activity principal

Tags: java, android, lista

Esto me pasa cuando uso la app después de cerrarla, la primera vez que la abro no tengo problemas.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.gep.guille.reportatemperatura, PID: 19524
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=853211, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.gep.guille.reportatemperatura/com.gep.guille.reportatemperatura.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3720)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3763)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
               Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
                  at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
                  at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
                  at com.gep.guille.reportatemperatura.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:134)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6470)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3716)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3763) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Acá esta el onActivityResult

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if ((requestCode == 853211) && (data !=null)) {

        String nombre=data.getStringExtra("NuevaCiudad");
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            listaCiudades.add(nombre);//(MainActivity.java:134)
        }


        String jsonObjetos = new Gson().toJson(listaCiudades);
        Log.i("json",jsonObjetos);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("listaCiudades", jsonObjetos);
        editor.commit();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

y acá el Activity de donde que  devuelve el Intent:

```
 public class NuevaCiudad extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.nueva_ciudad);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}
public void AgregarCiudad(View view) {
    EditText nueva_ciudad = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String nuevaCiudad = nueva_ciudad.getText().toString();
    if (nuevaCiudad.length() != 0) {

        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("NuevaCiudad", nuevaCiudad);

        setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
        finish();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.error_ingreso), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


 }
 }
```

Comment: miltons podrías agregar tu Activity completa? saludos.

Comment: cual es la linea 134?? alcanza a mostrar el Log.i("json",jsonObjetos);??

Comment: Hola @Elenasys @Maguz! Lo solucioné, el problema era que la lista en el onCreate la asignaba desde un Array con el metodo asList, pero después no me dejaba pasarle adds como si la lista fuera un Array. Así que asigne mediante un for las Strings. Saludos! y gracias!!

Comment: Ahí la agregué, gracias amigo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que la lista en el onCreate estaba asignaba desde un Array con el metodo asList(Array), pero, después me daba error al usar lista.add() "como si la lista fuera un Array". Así que asigne los valores de la lista mediante un for.

Resumiendo, el metodo asList(Array) sirve para asignar los valores de una lista a través de un Array pero después pareciera que la lista es como un Array (aunque respeta métodos como size())

Saludos! y gracias!!